# "Hardened Runtime is not enabled."

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave

I enabled it.
[image: Xcode]

[image: Xcode]

[image: Xcode]

But it's still giving me the same error. I'm trying to get this app notorized by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had a command line app included in the project. Apps will not be notarized if this happens which makes sense.

Comment: So did you harden the command line app or did you just remove it from the package?

Comment: Didn't do much with it. Waiting for the vendor to send an updated app but so far they haven't sent anything.